# Сложение значений ячеек таблицы на mysqli

Tags: mysql

В общем, нужно на mysqli сложить несколько ячеек таблицы. Таким вот образом, конечно же, не работает:

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT SUM(`priceall`) FROM `price` WHERE `session` = '".session_id()."'")->fetch_all();
```

Answer (score 1):

Сам разобрался.

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT `price`.*, (SELECT SUM(`priceall`)) AS `all` FROM `price` WHERE `session` = '".$ip_user."'")->fetch_array();
```